# How to display the correlation as numeric output in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, correlation

I want to select a variable from the data and show the correlation between the selected variable and the variable that selected before. Happiness is my data and score is my selected variable that I choose. I have an error "invalid argument type" Thank you.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel(),
    varSelectInput("variable", "Variable:", happiness),
    mainPanel(
       p(),
       p(),
     fluidRow(
          column(6,plotOutput(outputId="plotgraph1", width="300px",height="300px")),  
          column(6,plotOutput(outputId="plotgraph2", width="300px",height="300px")),
          column(6,tableOutput(outputId="correl.out"))

        )

  )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plotgraph1 <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(happiness, aes(x=!!input$variable,y=Score)) + geom_smooth()
    })
   output$plotgraph2 <- renderPlot({
           ggplot(happiness, aes(x=!!input$variable)) + geom_histogram()
    })


    output$correl.out <- renderTable({
        cor(x=!!input$variable,y=happiness$Score)
    })





  }
)




# We want to use multiple variables to select. 
if (FALSE) {
shinyApp(
 ui = fluidPage(
   varSelectInput("variables", "Variable:", happiness, multiple = TRUE),
   tableOutput("data")
 ),
 server = function(input, output) {
   output$data <- renderTable({
      if (length(input$variables) == 0) return(happiness)
      happiness %>% dplyr::select(!!!input$variables)
   }, rownames = TRUE)
 }
)}

  }
)
```

Comment: You can use:  `cor(x=happiness[,as.character(input$variable)],y=happiness$Score)` or `cor(x=happiness %>% dplyr::select(!!!input$variable),y=happiness$Score)`

Comment: It worked! Thank you!!